# If my android project depends on a .jar that has additional dependencies, should I have to include those in my project?

Tags: java, android, gradle, dependencies, noclassdeffounderror

I'm hitting an error in an Android Project and I'm unsure how to approach it.  I have a .jar that depends on Retrofit.  I have unit tests for that Jar that use Retrofit functionality and those run successfully.

I also have an android library project which depends on that jar, and when I try to call a method that is defined in the .jar, I get an error like the following:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lretrofit/RestAdapter$Builder;
at com.geoff.sdk.java.clients.RetrofitApiClient.<init>(RetrofitApiClient.java:17)
at com.geoff.sdk.java.clients.RetrofitApiClient.getInstance(RetrofitApiClient.java:29)
at com.geoff.sdk.java.clients.RetrofitApiClient.getRestAdapter(RetrofitApiClient.java:36)
```

I can resolve this issue by adding "compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'" to the build.gradle file of my Android library, but it seems like there should be a way to use this Jar without including the dependencies that it needs again.  I think there may be something not quite right with how I declared my dependencies in my Java project, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

All I did in my java project was add: "compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'"  into my dependencies portion of the build.gradle.

I was under the impression that dependencies were automatically exported, why does this seem to not be the case? and how can I resolve this.

Comment: have you added like this in build.gradle? compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'

Comment: Yes, I've done this in my Java project, and I found that I also needed to include it in the Android project :-/

Comment: I was talking about android project build.gradle. I was right then I guess.

Answer (score 0):

If you added it to your Grade.build file / Maven then the answer is no.